# SYBASE Nested query not running

Tags: sql, nested, sybase, subquery

I have a procedure I am writing and it contains a nested insert but the nested insert never runs. The nested insert's data is properly filled out by the select statements but the insert is never ran.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE search_string #inValue varchar(255)
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET nocount on
    CREATE TABLE #results (table_name sysname, column_name sysname)
    SELECT
    "INSERT #results SELECT DISTINCT '"
    + object_name(c.id)
    + "' as table_name, '"
    + c.name
    + "' as column_name FROM "
    + object_name(c.id)
    + " WHERE "
    + c.name
    + " LIKE '%"
    + @inValue
    + "%'"
    FROM syscolumns c, sysobjects o
    WHERE
    c.usertype in ( 1
    ,2
    ,18
    ,19
    ,24
    ,25
    ,42
    )
    AND o.type ='U'
    AND o.id = o.id
    AND c.length >= datalength(@invalue)
    SELECT * FROM #results
    END
```

This yields a bunch of insert statements that are never run.

Comment: . . What is your point?  This code isn't *running* anything, it is just doing string manipulations.  You need to use `exec()` if you want to run the resulting code.

Comment: I have executed the stored procedure and it does not run the insert statements into the #result table. That is what I was saying. Or are you stating that if I put the INSERT statement within an exec() it should run?

Comment: . . I thought you were expecting the `insert` code to run.  My best guess then would be that one of the string elements is `NULL`, causing the whole string to be `NULL`.

Comment: Replace `select "INSERT #results..."` with `EXEC ("INSERT #results...")`

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code :

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE search_string #inValue varchar(255)
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET nocount on
    CREATE TABLE #results (table_name sysname, column_name sysname)
    declare @sql varchar(255)

    select @sql = 'INSERT #results 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
     object_name(c.id)
      as table_name, 
     c.name
      as column_name FROM
     object_name(c.id)
      WHERE 
     c.name
      LIKE ''' +
     @inValue
     '%''
    FROM syscolumns c, sysobjects o
    WHERE
    c.usertype in ( 1
    ,2
    ,18
    ,19
    ,24
    ,25
    ,42
    )
    AND o.type =''U''
    AND o.id = o.id
    AND c.length >= datalength(''' + @invalue ''')'

    execute(@sql)

    SELECT * FROM #results
    END
```

I hope this help :)